# Disable Cmd + , in Safari

Tags: macos, keyboard, safari, shortcut

I'm currently doing a lot of chemistry writing in Google Docs. Google Docs is great for it because <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> formats as superscript and <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> formats as subscript... both of which supersaturate chemical writings (fear not, that's my only pun). Superscript works great, but Safari has an overriding <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> which brings up Preferences-General and highlights Homepage, so subscript doesn't work. I haven't yet found a way to disable Safari's particular shortcuts, so I'm hoping someone here does.

Comment: Have you tried doing it another web browser, like chrome/Firefox/third party browser?

Comment: 3rd party apps are the answer, here's some idea: http://lifehacker.com/5882684/the-best-keyboard-remapper-for-mac-os-x here's one that has an answer specifically per application http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/148845/osx-10-9-5-different-keyboard-layouts-per-application

Comment: I'd prefer to find the real solution rather than a workaround. I use Safari the majority of them time because it's more power efficient and, honestly, on the Mac it looks best. Chrome's mac application is a bit shoddy.

Comment: Chrome works! You can type your subscripts without issue!

Answer (score 5):

looks like this answer related to a similar problem might do the trick:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20692071/620141

in short:

1. Edit ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.symbolichotkeys.plist (you can use Xcode).
2. Find the code for kCGHotKeyLookUpWordInDictionary (70), and set 'enabled' to OFF (if it's not there just create an entry '70' with 'enabled' = OFF).
3. Restart your system

**EDIT:**
In your case, it should be:

```
Key Down
    Characters: ,
    Unicode:        44 / 0x2c
    Keys:       ⌘,
    Key Code:   43 / 0x2b
    Modifiers:  1048848 / 0x100110
```

so you should be using key code **43** with modifier **1048848**

Extra help:

- [answer's source & extra guidance](http://krypted.com/mac-os-x/defaults-symbolichotkeys/)
- [Tool to find the key code (older macs only)](http://softwares.bajram.com/utilities)
- [Alternative tool that works on Yosemite (Apple Store, free)](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/key-codes/id414568915?mt=12)

Comment: This looks promising, but the tools to find the key codes are failing me. Either that or I'm having trouble understanding them. Could you help me find the code for Command + , and then, if it works, I'll mark your response as answer.

Comment: @Silew sorry I couldn't get back to you earlier. I've updated the answer, you should (untested) be using  key code **43** with modifier **1048848**

Lemme know how it went

Comment: I'm sorry, I must be doing something wrong. There was no 43 key, so I made one. I added an item 'enabled' to 43 and set it as NO. (every time I made a change I restarted to see if it would be fixed) So then I followed the format of the other keys and created a value dictionary. To 'value' I added 'type' and set it as 'standard,' then added 'parameters' as 'item 0 = 1048848' and 'item 1 = 44'. It's still not working. Do you know from that description what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > App shortcuts > <kbd>+</kbd>

Title it "Preferences..." and remap it to <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>+</kbd>, and voila, you can now use <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>,</kbd> in Google Docs.